# Canon 5D Mark III - Printing at 40 x 30 inches help

Tags: canon, image-quality, printing, camera, ppi

I took a photograph and would like to print it at 40x30 inches.

I have RAW files - what PPI/resolution should I import this image in? I am slightly confused by it. These images should be crisp!

Thank you!

Comment: If you are taking it to a high street photo processor, give them a jpg saved at 100% quality & tell them you want it printing at 40"x30". They will do the rest. if anything different, you will need to give us more detail.

Comment: What resolution should you *import* it in? The full native file...

Answer (score 1):

Preference for PPI will vary based on what it is and how close people will be to it looking at it. For looking up close at a photo the most you should need is 300ppi but it can definitely still look good at lower. The size you can print while maintaining a certain ppi is based on the size of the sensor in your camera. Your sensor is 5760 x 3840 pixels so you divide that by the amount of pixels per inch you want in your print. If you print at 200ppi then 5760/200=28.8 and 3840/200=19.2. So the largest you can print and keep around 200ppi is about 30x20. If you print at 40x30 you will be closer to around 130ppi and that might be ok depending on what you are doing with it, but it likely won't look very crisp up close at that size.

You also have to take into account if you cropped the photo any. When you do that you remove pixels from the image so in those situations you would start with less than 5760 and 3840 to calculate it and maintaining the same ppi would mean a smaller print.

Comment: I'd check the printer's requirements first. I get a lot of large print done & what my printer wants is an sRGB jpg & an output size. I don't do any work on the DPI calculation, they do that. I don't even know whether they re-sample intentionally or their printer does it at runtime. All I know is so long as I've a reasonable start-point [somewhere above 150 DPI, I get back a good print. Their structure won't let me send them some teeny image that would end up at 30 DPI.

Comment: 30DPI (or even lower...) is OK for billboards... Required definitiion decreases when normal viewing distance and the viewing distance increases like the size of the picture. If you do the math you find that the required size in pixels is constant. And to give you and idea a "Letter" page printed at 300PPI (very crisp) is 8.5Mpix, 34MPix at 600PPI. You never need more than 12-16Mpix for a print, whatever its size.

Comment: @xenoid, the CoC standard for image sharpness (30um dots on a FF sensor) requires less than 1MP for any size print when viewed "normally." But dots on a sensor (image resolution) is different from pixels (sensor resolution).

Comment: The CoC used for DOF (film era) is 1/1780th of the diagonal which translates roughly to 3MPx.

Answer (score 0):

The main factor in how large you can print is the same as it has always been; it  is the size of the negative (36x24mm) and the image quality (IQ) of the negative (raw file) in terms of detail/sharpness/grain(noise).

If the image looks good on your monitor at 100% zoom, then simply divide the sensor resolution (5760) by your monitor resolution to determine the maximum print size. For instance, the monitor of my MBPR is running at 102PPI; so 5760/102 would equal a 56.5" wide print that will look just as good.

But the chances are good that it will not look "crisp" at 100% zoom due to a lack of IQ. So if looks acceptable at 50% zoom, then divide the sensor resolution by 2x the monitor resolution, e.g. 5760/204=28.25". But that is not large enough to meet your requirement, so then you would have to attempt to upsample and sharpen the image to an acceptable degree.

Also note that your sensor's aspect ratio is 3:2 and you are wanting to print at a 2.66:2 ratio, so the image will have to be cropped some from the sides. That is going to reduce the sensor resolution remaining (it will be less than 5760 on the long edge).

Edit: an easier answer is to just enlarge the image on your screen so that it equals the desired print size. E.g. 25% of the image occupies ~10"(25% of the desired print size) on your monitor. If it looks good on your monitor to you, then it will look good printed (because photo printers output at a higher resolution than any computer monitor does).

Comment: We're now throwing more & more complex answers at what appears to be a very simple, if rather confused, consumer-level question. Not sure we're helping. We need clarification of intent from the OP. I've been doing computer graphics 30 years & couldn't tell you the dot pitch of my monitor… it's just never really been that important a detail.

Comment: @Tetsujin, If you don't know your resolution it is easy to figure out. E.g. my monitor is running at 1440x900 and it is 14" wide (display area). But I will add an even easier answer... FWIW, I have never had any print shop upsample an image for me if it was sent at too low of a resolution.

Comment: This is information I can find in seconds. I've two 27" 2560x1440 screens, that makes them about 108 DPI, 0.23 dot pitch - but it simply has never mattered. I've never had a print shop *noticeably* up or downscale, but they'll take anything within reason I send them & they send me back what I asked for. There's some calculation goes on somewhere, but it's not important I have to deal with it. They do.

Comment: @Tetsujin, there's no calculations/resampling that they do... it's just that you don't really need anywhere near 300ppi. It's not until the square pixel shape starts becoming visually apparent in the print that you have run out of pixel resolution (<100ppi), and most images start to fall apart well before that due to lower image resolution  (actual).

Comment: There's pretty much always resampling of some sort, unless I'm sending them an image at the exact DPI of their printer. Again, this is not something the consumer needs to worry about.

Comment: @Tetsujin, *resampling* is changing the pixel resolution by compressing/combining pixels or adding pixels. They *scale* an image instead. If the submitted print/image resolution is lower than the printer resolution/capability, then you get print/image resolution results. And if the submitted print/image resolution is greater than the printer resolution/capability, then you get printer resolution results... in this case there is a loss of resolution as if the image had been resampled, but for a different reason.

Comment: Again, this is not something the consumer needs to worry about, which was my initial point.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there mostly. There is variation in what the answer would be depending on the situation. But at the same time your options for who can print it are sometimes limited. I have to give my preferred resolution where I print from. But even though there is a routine way to calculate it you can still improve that sometimes with software or get the same results at lower than expected ppi. If you've never printed before its likely you won't be satisfied with the first attempt for one reason or another and it may have nothing to do with size. Ive tossed prints in the trash that looked great on my monitor but turned out to be not bright enough once I sent them in to print and I was no longer viewing the printed version on a backlit screen. Its something to learn the basics of and then do a little bit of trial and error just like with learning to take those pictures that are worthy of the prints.